# Way to display non-public events to employees

Tags: civievent, acl

Our organization has a variety of public events as well as private events. In many cases, I need volunteers/employees to see the private events so they can register to assist, etc.

Is it possible to have a means that when an employee logs into the website, the non-public events are listed in upcoming events?  I am somewhat familiar with ACL and have an employees ACL rule that works in other aspects. I would like a way to have the employee log-in and see all events.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do this with an additional acl.

tested this on a client's site and it seemed to work

But I don't know you exact needs, you might want 'all' instead of 'edit' in the form

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I will experiment with this and see if I can get it. Thank You