# Hiding Some Events From Public View but Visible to Some Users

Tags: civievent, joomla

I asked a similar question over 2 years ago and there was one possible solution that was offered, however, it did not work for me. I wanted to revisit this to seek some guidance.

Our organization has a variety of Public Events that are visible on the front end's listed of upcoming events. Our organization also has a variety of private events for our team members only that I do not want to be displayed on the public calendar.

Is there a way to have all events listed in Upcoming Events but have some of those only visible to a certain group of logged in members (our staff).

For example, the public facing page, the visitor would see:

Public Fundraiser Event

Public Training Program

Public Fundraiser Event

Public Fundraiser Event

And then when one of our team members (assigned to a group in both Joomla and CiviCRM), the page would look like:

Public Fundraiser Event

Private Team Meeting

Private Training

Public Training Program

Public Fundraiser Event

Private Meeting

Private Meeting

Public Fundraiser Event

The solution that was offered previously was using ACL's to show all events to the particular group. This doesn't work (for me) on the Front End upcoming events.

Comment: looks like previous Q was https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20119/way-to-display-non-public-events-to-employees (to save others wondering what approach was not useful)

Comment: That's correct...Thank You